# Networkx Graph: Spectral_Layout

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a network graph using Networkx but not getting the requisite output.

Required Output:

[image]

This output was created by defining the pos which is as follows:

```
 pos = {"A": (0,0),
      'P_b_A_B': (1,0),
      "B": (2,0),
      "C": (3, 0),
       "H": (4,-2),
       "E" : (0,-4),
       "G": (1,-4),
       "P_b_G_H": (2,-4),
       "P_sb": (5,-2)
      }
nx.draw(G, node_size=1200, node_color="skyblue",pos = pos,with_labels = True )
```

But as the flow is dependent on the output of the previous process, I need to draw the graph accordingly. I tried to use spectral_layout of networkx which gave the following output

[image]

code used:

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=1500, node_color="skyblue", pos=nx.spectral_layout(G))
plt.title("spectral")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's likely you'll have to write a custom function to calculate positions for nodes based the expected outputs from your previous step.  I doubt that there is a layout algorithm that will calculate exactly what you need out of the box.  

We could give more help/advice here if you gave more details about the potential outputs of that previous step and how those changes affect the desired plot.

Comment: Yes, just go around it by writing an algorithm. This is material movement plan and the path followed by different material is an input from the user and hence difficult to derive any kind of mapping. In the algorithm, the pos is determined by the what is the next adjacent items. The branching (whether the node will be above or below the next node) is decided by direction variable which I have introduced. Thanks